# How to pass a selected spinner item between spinners?

Tags: java, android, methods, spinner, android-spinner

After a thorough search and quite a lot of thinking, I couldn't find a solution to the following problem in AndroidStudio:

I have 2 spinners (input and output). I want to pass the value of the input spinner to a method that is called upon selection of a value of the output spinner (onItemSelected). The regarding code passage looks as follows:

```
private void setupSpinnerListeners() {

    spinnerLengthInput.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String itemSelectedInSpinnerLengthInput = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            checkIfConvertingFromMeter(itemSelectedInSpinnerLengthInput);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    spinnerLengthOutput.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String itemSelectedInSpinnerLengthOutput = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            updateOutputTextfield(itemSelectedInSpinnerLengthInput, itemSelectedInSpinnerLengthOutput);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

I want the String itemSelectedInSpinnerLengthInput (that gets its value from the input spinner) to be available in the onItemSelected method of the output spinner. How to accomplish this?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Create a global variable INSIDE the setupSpinnerListeners Method, that is an array with length 1. The it'll work as I had intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use [`OnItemSelectedListener`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html).

Then create a globalVariable to get the `String` to your first `Spinner` as follows :

```
String FirstValue = "";
```

Then you'll need to call this :

```
spinnerLengthInput.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
spinnerLengthOutput.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Of course you'll need to `implements OnItemSelectedListener`

Then inside you can do the same that you were doing.

```
 @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View view, int position,long id)
{
     FirstValue = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        checkIfConvertingFromMeter(itemSelectedInSpinnerLengthInput);
}
```

Then in your other `Spinner` use the `FirstValue` value.

Comment: I failed to recreate your suggestion - I think I am just not "fluent" enough to know how to do it. Would it be too much to ask you for a example of a mainActivity with that being made?

Comment: Nevermind, meanwhile I got to run it, and it works. Thanks for your suggestion! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change **itemSelectedInSpinnerLengthOutput** as a global variable. After that, you can easy access to it in the onItemSelected method of the output spinner

```
String itemSelectedInSpinnerLengthInput; // global variable
    private void setupSpinnerListeners() {

        spinnerLengthInput.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                itemSelectedInSpinnerLengthInput = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                checkIfConvertingFromMeter(itemSelectedInSpinnerLengthInput);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        spinnerLengthOutput.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String itemSelectedInSpinnerLengthOutput = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                if(itemSelectedInSpinnerLengthInput != null){
                        updateOutputTextfield(itemSelectedInSpinnerLengthInput, itemSelectedInSpinnerLengthOutput);
                }else{
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please select input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     ...
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Hope this help

Comment: This does not do the trick, as this will result in a null object reference. When initializing the global variable you don't give it a value.

Comment: so you should check null value in onItemSelected method of the output spinner

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what you mean by that. Could you please further explain?

Comment: Even though I am not a big fan of that toast popping up at the startup of my app, it has fixed the issue and I can go on with my work - thank you very much!

Comment: If you don't like toast message. Just do 2 steps like this:
1. Disable output spinner when start 
2. When user select input spinner -> enable output spinner

Comment: That would be a viable option of course. Probably I am just not creative enough :P
Thank you for your suggestions!