# How to pass value from onItemSelected to another spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have got 3 spinners in a activity which are populated from webservices with 3 methods as follows using loopj. I want to pass the value of "ida" from `onItemSelected` of `spinner1` to `spinner3`. So how can I pass a value from one method to another.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     getSpinner1();
}

private void getSpinner1() {
    RestClient1.getForSpinner1(  
.
.                       
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long ida) {
                     getSpinner2(ida);    
}

private void getSpinner2(Long ida) {
    RestClient2.getForSpinner2(  
.
.                       
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long idb) {
                     getSpinner3(ida,idb);    
}

.
.
private void getSpinner3(Long ida,Long idb) {
    RestClient3.getForSpinner3(  
.
.                       
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long idc) {   
}
```

Comment: I am confused. what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I am populating spinner2 based on spinner1 and spinner3 based on spinner1 and spinner2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a selected spinner item between spinners?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806344/how-to-pass-a-selected-spinner-item-between-spinners)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use OnItemSelectedListener. There is a bried description on how to found here at StackOverFlow - [how-to-pass-a-selected-spinner-item-between-spinners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806344/how-to-pass-a-selected-spinner-item-between-spinners)

I have used this before and it worked a charm.

EDIT: To summarise @Skizo-ozᴉʞS solution, the following -

Then create a globalVariable to get the String to your first Spinner as follows :

```
String FirstValue = "";
```

Then you'll need to call this :

```
spinnerLengthInput.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
spinnerLengthOutput.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Of course you'll need to implements OnItemSelectedListener

Then inside you can do the same that you were doing.

```
 @Override
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View view, int position,long id)
{
 FirstValue = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    checkIfConvertingFromMeter(itemSelectedInSpinnerLengthInput);
}
```

Then in your other Spinner use the FirstValue value.

Comment: Try to summarise your answer. Don't post links only as links may change sometime.

Comment: @indramurari - New to this, is this what you meant by summarise?

Comment: @AndreOosthuizen I cannot use for Long? only for String i can use?

Comment: @AndreOosthuizen I tried, but couldnt use FirstValue in                      getSpinner3(FirstValue,idb); even though i declared as global variable. i get "Cannot refer to a non-final variable FirstValue inside an inner class defined in a different method" error. any suggestion please